# get single object from string using java

Tags: java, json

I want to read single object from string . Here is my output string  :

```
{\"session\": {\"application_id\":\"xxxx\",\"nonce\":\"xxxxx\",\"user_id\":\"xxxxx\",\"created_at\":\"xxxxx\",\"token\":\"xxxx\",\"id\":\"xxx\"}}
```

i want to get "token" from this string . how can i read it?
i had tried using below code :

```
JSONObject element = new JSONObject(<string object i.e. response>);
String token = object.getString("token");
```

but getting below error :

```
constructor JSONObject in class JSONObject cannot be applied to given types;  
required: no arguments
found: String
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Can anybody help me for this?

Comment: I can't reproduce this error with your current code. Also you are showing us how you create `element` but we still don't know what `object` from which you invoke `getString("token")` is. I suspect where it could come from, but if my suspicion is true, your code should work.

Comment: 1) Make sure you have imported `org.json.JSONObject` 2) Then extract the token with `.getJSONObject("session").getString("token")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using the wrong import.
It seems that you use [com.google.gson.JSONObject](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html) instead of [org.json.JSONObject](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/json/JSONObject.html).

Edit:
Furthermore your code is wrong. You need `element.getJSONObject("session").getString("token")` not `object.getString("token")`

Edit: 
Since the OP still has problems here some tested code:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JsonTest 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        String json = "{\"session\": {\"token\":\"xxxx\"}}";
        JSONObject jObject= new JSONObject(json);
        String token = jObject.getJSONObject("session").getString("token");
        System.out.printf("Token %s" , token);
    }
}
```

Comment: `object.getString("token")` it looks like a typo in the question while posting it. The OP also needs to extract the `session` node first, and then extract the `token` property value from the `session` object.

Comment: @Lyubomyr Shaydariv yes, I was just editing the answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: i have used : import org.json.simple.JSONObject

Comment: It was my mistake : object.getString("token"); . it is : element.getString("token");

Comment: I am not able to use this line : element.getJSONObject("session").getString("token") as it is having error.. not able to access getJSONObject .

Comment: It is not org,json.simple.JSONObject it is org.json.JSONObject

Comment: i have changed JSON jar and use @arigion's code...it is working now..thanks